# Convert PLN to number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Importing a trial balance into excel has the currently PLN (Polish Zloty) the issue I have is that I am struggling to convert this to number as it is coming in text.
-PLN123,456 needs to be -123,456
PLN789,012 needs to be 789,012

I can eliminate the PLN for the positive values by using a right(cell) formula - but this doesn't work with the negatives. Is anyone able to help?

Thank you in advance

I have tried value(cell) I have tried right(cell) but struggling to find an answer that works on all lines

Comment: Try: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"PLN",)+0`

Answer (score 0):

So, a different approach:

[image]

```
IF(LEFT(A3,1)="-",-1,1)*SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("N",A3,1)+1,7),",",)*1
```

The if() sorts the negative, finding the "N" +1 gets the start of the number and substitute() removes the ",". If you want the comma then format the cell appropriately.